# Upload file webdriver sendKey with no ID field

Tags: java, file-upload, webdriver

Hi I was wondering if i could use this command when there is no ID field, it seems like the button accepts input. I tried .sendKeys but it doesn't seem to do anything, places said don't use the .click(); command after.

Here is the html for the button.

```
<button class="md-button-icon mt-toolbar-button md-button md-default-theme ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" accept="image/*" ng-model="chatFiles" ng-disabled="!sessionStarted" ng-show="!chatMessage" ng-file-select="" tabindex="0" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-hidden="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-disabled="false">
   <mt-icon class="ng-isolate-scope" height="24" width="24" icon=" attachment" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">
   <span>menu</span>
   <input type="file" accept="image/*" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;" tabindex="-1" ng-file-generated-elem="true">
</button>
```

This is my code in webdriver:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/md-card/md-content/div/div[2]/button[2]")));  
WebElement Upload = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/md-card/md-content/div/div[2]/button[2]"));
Upload.sendKeys("C:/Users/elsid/Desktop/Eclipse/Workspace/NG - Mentored/Autoit/test.png");
```

This is the code from the uploaded image all the way down to the button again.

```
   <li class="ng-scope mt-chat-mine" layout="row" ng-class="{ 'mt-chat-mine': message.isMine()}" ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <!--

         ngIf: !message.isMine() 

        -->
        <!--

         ngIf: message.type == 1 

        -->
        <!--

         ngIf: message.type == 2 

        -->
        <img class="chat-image ng-scope" ng-if="message.type == 2" ng-src="http://mentoredapp.perrysysdev.com/usercontent/SessionFiles/8040eeaa-3584-4a13-b54e-a16bfadd6433.jpg" src="http://mentoredapp.perrysysdev.com/usercontent/SessionFiles/8040eeaa-3584-4a13-b54e-a16bfadd6433.jpg"></img>
        <!--

         end ngIf: message.type == 2 

        -->
        <!--

         ngIf: message.type == 3 

        -->
        <!--

         ngIf: message.isMine() 

        -->
        <img class="avatar ng-scope" ng-if="message.isMine()" ng-src="http://mentoredapp.perrysysdev.com/usercontent/TutorProfilePictures/25f586a2-5031-49a5-94a3-e65305faed8a.png" src="http://mentoredapp.perrysysdev.com/usercontent/TutorProfilePictures/25f586a2-5031-49a5-94a3-e65305faed8a.png"></img>
        <!--

         end ngIf: message.isMine() 

        -->
    </li>
    <!--

     end ngRepeat: message in messages 

    -->

</ul>
<div class="text-box" layout="row">

    <textarea id="chat-message-box" class="message-box ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" placeholder="Send a message.." ng-disabled="!sessionStarted" mt-enter="sendChatMessage()" flex="" ng-model="chatMessage" aria-multiline="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-disabled="false"></textarea>

<button class="md-button-icon mt-toolbar-button md-button md-default-theme ng-hide" ng-transclude="" ng-show="chatMessage" ng-disabled="!chatMessage" ng-click="sendChatMessage()" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true" aria-disabled="true" disabled="disabled"></button>

<button class="md-button-icon mt-toolbar-button md-button md-default-theme ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" accept="image/*" ng-model="chatFiles" ng-disabled="!sessionStarted" ng-show="!chatMessage" ng-file-select="" ng-click="clicked" tabindex="0" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-hidden="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-disabled="false">

    <mt-icon class="ng-isolate-scope" height="24" width="24" icon=" attachment" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"></mt-icon>
    <span></span>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;" tabindex="-1" ng-file-generated-elem="true"></input>

</button>
```

Comment: Is that file input tag hidden?

Comment: not sure how can i check? it says hidden in the html, also the <span> is grayed out

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the xpath little bit more to find the element easily

```
By xpath = By.xpath("//span[text()='menu']");
By fileTag = By.cssSelector("[type='file']");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath)));  
WebElement Upload = driver.findElement(fileTag);
Upload.sendKeys("C:/Users/elsid/Desktop/Eclipse/Workspace/NG - Mentored/Autoit/test.png");
```

If the file input is hidden only way to handle that is JavaScript and set the attribute. Try the following code

```
String filePath = "C:/Users/elsid/Desktop/Eclipse/Workspace/NG - Mentored/Autoit/test.png";
String script = "document.querySelector(\"[type='file']\").setAttribute('value','" + filePath + "');";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
```

I assumed that's the only file input tag on that page and **not hidden**. If not you may have to adjust the file selector

Comment: ok thanks, I assume it's hidden says overflow-hidden. I will try a java robot to input everything.

Comment: can you check the 2nd line i think it has a syntax error, eclipse is throwing an error, invalid character constant. I am using Java

Comment: now giving me error on "');" saying Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

Comment: @Elsid Right. This is what happen if you do not use IDE. was missing **;** at the end of second line

Comment: What is the error? And, expected is, it's going to set the filepath directly and since it's hidden you wont see it

Comment: there is no error it executes, my webdriver script stops at asserting that the image was uploading. So the script is working, but the image doesn't upload.

Comment: yes, I also use AutoIT and it works, it's just autoit is unreliable so i wanted to figure out a different method.

Comment: Ok in that case, can you upload a file and provide me the html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75526/discussion-between-saifur-and-elsid).